# How can I zip multiple images within my App

Tags: iphone, image, compression, zip, send

Within my App I'm using the Camera to take several pictures. These pictures need to be sended in one time. For that reason I'm trying to implement a function to compress the photo's I took.

I've been looking on the internet for several libraries which I could use within my project. I came out with Objective Zip (http://code.google.com/p/objective-zip/wiki/GettingStarted). However the only thing I succeeded was compressing (or decompressing) text-files. But compressing (or decompressing) photo's is not mentioned.

I've succeeded with converting my token photo's to a NSData object. Now i want to compress them to a Zip file. Is there anyone who have had experience with these kind of functions.

Help is greatly appreciated!

**Edit**

I'm now using the Objective Zip library but my App keeps crashing. Still getting the known error "Thread 1: Program reveived signal : "SIGARBT" ".  I'm trying to zip one image I took with the camera and stored in the documents directory.

Within the snippet you can see that I'm calling the photo I took and zipping it with the ZipFile method. In the end I'm sending my zip-file as an email attachment.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
-(IBAction)sendID{



    NSString *docDir3 = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *docDir4 = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *pngFilePath3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/photo.png",docDir3];

    // Create the zip file
    ZipFile *zipFile = [[ZipFile alloc] initWithFileName:docDir4 mode:ZipFileModeCreate];

    // Read the files in the data directory
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *files = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:pngFilePath3 error:&error];

    //ZipWriteStream *stream1= [zipFile writeFileInZipWithName:@"abc.txt" fileDate:[NSDate //dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-86400.0] compressionLevel:ZipCompressionLevelBest];


    // Write each file to our zip
    for (NSString *filename in files) {

        // Write the file
        ZipWriteStream *stream = [zipFile writeFileInZipWithName:filename compressionLevel:ZipCompressionLevelBest];

        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pngFilePath3];

        [stream writeData:data];

        [stream finishedWriting];
    }

    // Close the zip file
    [zipFile close];

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"Test.zip"];
    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate=self;

    //NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(viewImage, 1);

    [picker addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"application/zip" fileName:@"Test.zip"];

    Class mailclass = (NSClassFromString(@"MFMailComposeViewController"));
    if([mailclass canSendMail]){
        [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Hope anyone can help me out.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread, but here's how I zip up multiple files using Objective-Zip:

```
- (NSString*) objectiveZip:(NSArray*)passedFiles
{
    NSString *outputPath = [self getOutputDirectory];

    NSString *zipFileName = @"MyZip.zip";

    outputPath = [outputPath stringByAppendingString:zipFileName];

    //Create a zip file for writing
    ZipFile *zipFile= [[ZipFile alloc] initWithFileName:outputPath mode:ZipFileModeCreate];

    //Add all the files, write to its stream and close it
    for(NSString *string in passedFiles)
    {
        NSString *fileName = string;

        NSLog(@"Add file to zip: %@", fileName);

        ZipWriteStream *stream1= [zipFile writeFileInZipWithName:fileName fileDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-86400.0] compressionLevel:ZipCompressionLevelBest];

        [stream1 writeData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:info.pdfUrl]]];
        [stream1 finishedWriting];
    }

    // Close the zip file
    [zipFile close];

    return outputPath;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best zip lib I've found is [SSZipArchive](https://github.com/samsoffes/ssziparchive). Give that one a shot.

Comment: thanks for your comment. However within the readme file of this library says 'Currently it only supports unzipping. In the future, creating zip files will be supported.' So I don't think this library will be very usefull to me.

Answer (score 0):

NSString *temp=[[[makeZip textFieldAtIndex:0]text]stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"zip"];

NSString *zippedPath = [pathString stringByAppendingPathComponent:temp];

NSMutableArray *inputPaths=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

```
    for (int i=0; i<[selectedRows count]; i++) {
                 [inputPaths addObject:[pathStringstringByAppendingPathComponent:[selectedRows objectAtIndex:i]]];
        }
        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:zippedPath])
        {
        [SSZipArchive createZipFileAtPath:zippedPath withFilesAtPaths:inputPaths];
            [directoryContents addObject:temp];
            [tblview reloadData];
        }
```